# Why do I get '.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running' regardless of how I build it and agent?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I wanted to do something similar to:

https://devsdaily.com/azure-devops-how-to-run-console-applications-on-azure-pipeline/

To run a [little conversion tool.](https://dev.azure.com/ChrisPepperSandBox/Documentation/_git/Documentation)

But so far I am getting

> "D:\a\1\s\MakeMasterMarkDown.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running"

I've built the exe as above. The only thing (i think) I'm doing differently is that I'm doing it in .yaml.

I have recreated the project with a sample version of what I am trying to do here:
https://dev.azure.com/ChrisPepperSandBox/Documentation/_git/Test?path=/azure-pipeline.yml

(which doesn't run because I don't wan't to pay for a parrallel pipeline on it, its a copy and paste of something I have from somewhere I cant share)

The codebase for the tool is also there:
https://dev.azure.com/ChrisPepperSandBox/Documentation/_git/Documentation

Which is a .netcore3.1 project and I've tried it as a

- 32bit
- 64bit
- Arm .exe :S
  (Which you can see in the test repo)

I have tried specifying the build agent as:

- windows-latest
- windows-2019
- windows-2016

The exe runs locally as both 64 and 32 bit on my machine.

Am I missing anything obvious?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to see the yaml for the relevant pipeline, which is likely important.  If it isn't too long, can you add it to the question here please?

Comment: Is the pipeline this one? https://dev.azure.com/ChrisPepperSandBox/Documentation/_git/Test?path=/azure-pipeline.yml

Comment: Yes that's the one :) thank you for taking a look :)

Comment: Ah thank you I just noticed I put the wrong link in my question I've updated the above to have the link to the pipeline, sorry about that!

Comment: To confirm, you build the exe locally, add it to git and push, then are trying to run the exe on windows-latest etc.?  The details of your local machine might end up being relevant :/  Is it possible for you to have a pipeline which builds the exe (on e.g. windows-latest) and commits it to the relevant repository?  You can use e.g. PowerShell tasks to access git commands.  Not sure if this is a sensible strategy, but would hopefully eliminate your local machine as a point of failure.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I'll try that this weekend

Comment: Hi Chris, hope you have a wonderful day, do Andrew's suggestions work?

Comment: Sorry, it took me ages to actually give this a go. Yes it worked :) I'm still not sure why!